# Bootstrap's tooltip moves table cells to right a bit on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.1.1 for my project. Each cell in my table contains data like `000` or `111`. On hover, I want to display this data as a tooltip. So far, this works. However, when I hover over a `<td>`, all adjacent cells shift to the right.

[Here's my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEqF2/)

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="matrisHeader">
                &nbsp;
            </th>
            <th data-original-title="111"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                PÇ1
            </th>
            <th data-original-title="222"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                PÇ2
            </th>
            <th data-original-title="333" data-toggle="tooltip"
                data-placement="bottom" title="">
                PÇ3
            </th>
            <th data-original-title="444"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"title="">
                PÇ4
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th data-original-title="555" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                 title="">
                ÖÇ1
            </th>
            <td data-original-title="666"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="777"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="888"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="999"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th data-original-title="000" data-toggle="tooltip"
                data-placement="bottom" title="">
                ÖÇ2
            </th>
            <td data-original-title="aaa"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="bbb"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="ccc"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="ddd"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th data-original-title="eee" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                title="">
                ÖÇ3
            </th>
            <td data-original-title="fff"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="ggg"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="hhh"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td data-original-title="iii"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You have to add the `data-container="body"` as per documentation.

```
<td data-original-title="999" data-container="body"
 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="">
 &nbsp;
</td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uEqF2/2/

Comment: Why Cannot I see this Bootstrap's documentation? Nice. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's part of bootstrap, I think it's jQuery specific.  Check their documentation.

Comment: It is in the part that is labeled **Tooltips in button groups and input groups require special setting** not specifically mentioning tables but the idea is if the tooltip overlaps it will be able to show without interference.

Comment: This fix doesn't work for content that's been dynamically inserted into the page.

Comment: In a big <TABLE> with tooltip on some <TR>, I had the same shifting problem which made my page really slow. Thanks to data-container="body", it fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the "data-container" at this way:

```
// initalize boostrap tooltip
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            container: 'body'
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Bryce Easley answer correct, but I had to follow this for angular with ngx-bootstrap

```html
<td 
    container="body"                
    tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
    triggers="click">icon
</td>
```

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#append-to-body