# Bootstrap tooltip pushed my right side contents away

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I added `tooltip` in my table's 2nd column but it is pushiing my last column away.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Default</td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Defaultson</td>
        <td>def@somemail.com</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr class="success">
        <td>Success</td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap's tooltip moves table cells to right a bit on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938008/bootstraps-tooltip-moves-table-cells-to-right-a-bit-on-hover)

Comment: Read it somewhere: You need to create an element inside a td and apply a tooltip to it, because a tooltip itself is a div, and when it is placed after a td element it brakes table layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `data-container="body"` in your *HTML* in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Default</td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Defaultson</td>
        <td>def@somemail.com</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr class="success">
        <td>Success</td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or can add `{container: 'body'}` to your *JavaScript* in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Default</td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Defaultson</td>
        <td>def@somemail.com</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr class="success">
        <td>Success</td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want your `tooltip` to be on text instead of `td` you can create an inner element like `span` and add `tooltip` on that item. Try this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Default</td>
        <td>
          <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Defaultson</span>
        </td>
        <td>def@somemail.com</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr class="success">
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>
          <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Doe</span></td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Default</td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!" data-container="body">Defaultson</td>
        <td>def@somemail.com</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr class="success">
        <td>Success</td>
        <td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!" data-container="body">Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

just add `data-container="body"`

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!" data-container="body">Defaultson</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my tooltip appear from td center i want it from text center.

Answer (score 2):

try this way :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Default</td>
        <td><p data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Defaultson</p></td>
        <td>def@somemail.com</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr class="success">
        <td>Success</td>
        <td><p data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Doe</p></td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my tooltip appear from td center i want it from text center.

Answer (score 0):

edit `<tbody>` like

```
    <tbody>
  <tr data-toggle="tooltip">
    <td>Default</td>
    <td  data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Defaultson</td>
    <td>def@somemail.com</td>
  </tr>      
  <tr class="success" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <td>Success</td>
    <td  data-placement="top" title="Hooray!">Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

this. put `data-toggle="tooltip"` into `<tr>` tag